# How do I construct and populate a wx.Grid with data from a database (python/wxpython)

Tags: python, sqlite, grid, wxpython

I've been viewing the wx demo for hours and just can't wrap my head around this.

I need to pull info from my database and store it's columns and values in a grid for viewing only (as of now)

Could someone make me a example script of how to do it just so I can then implement it with my own data. The grid I need is fixed positioned and will fit inside a panel (a page of a wx.notebook) I know how to do that part but how to get the grid inside the panel and populate it confuses me.

Additional info: my database holds customer info (name,phone,email)

Comment: Just to clarify I'm not asking someone to do my work for me, But I really can't seem to understand what the demo is doing. (grids always confuse me)

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at [Dabo](http://www.dabodev.com/), which is a framework mainly aimed at writing wxPython GUIs that interact with databases.

Comment: +1 You are right, that demo is really cryptic. Couldn't understand myself (and I has some experience with wx...)

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking at the grid demo using wx.grid.PyGridTableBase and related, you're right: it seems a really cryptic code.
However, the key method is:

```
def GetValue(self, row, col):
        return 'something'
```

the idea is that if you have your data in

```
self.data = [[1,2,3,4],
             [5,6,7,8],
             ........
             ]
```

then this will put your data in the corresponding cells:

```
def GetValue(self, row, col):
     return str( self.data[row][column] )
```

(`self.data` represents your database)

For other more simple examples using wx.grid.Grid with static data or with data fom a MySQL database you can check [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-an-introduction-to-grids/) and [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/307431/populating-wx.grid-with-mysql-table)

The method used to fill a cell with wx.grid.Grid is:

```
mygrid.SetCellValue(row, col, databasevalue4rowcol)
```

Comment: I have to be honest. That confused me even more. Is it possible you could write a snippet code as if you were going to add it to your app. I just need to see how someone else would go about the process.

Comment: @lsov5 what exactly is the demo you are looking at ? look edit

Comment: @isov5 I assume that, which demo program exactly ?

Comment: @joaquin I appreciate your efforts in answering this question. I've seen those links in your answer but I find them very primitive. I myself am new to wxGrid and I thought of your method. But isn't there something more convenient than that? Even in the very old VB6 we had just 2 or 3 lines to bring in the data to a grid. It's sad if we don't have such a thing today on something as new as wxWidgets. Thanks anyway. BTW I'm using C++ and not Python.

Comment: @itsols You can put the data into the grid p.e using SetCellValue inside a loop taking rows and values from p.e. a list of pairs (row,value) or whatever iterable you create with your data of read from your database. This takes 3 lines.

Comment: @joaquin Agreed. However, this approach requires more overall effort compared to the VB approach. For example, in order to make cells editable, I'll have to code the click and update events of cells as well. But in VB, those same three lines do the trick. In fact to make things better, we had a design-time property like 'editable' that would make the grid contents editable. I don't recall the exact event but that's how it used to be. If I get the time, I'd like to write a class extension for wxGrid that would do this. But I wanted to make sure first if it weren't available. Thanks again!

Comment: And one more thing... Thank you for clarifying the feature set and what needs to be done. +1 for our efforts although your examples are from Python :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.1, 2.7, 5.3], 'B': [2, 10, 9], 'C': [3.3, 5.4, 1.5], 'D': [4, 7, 15]},
                      index = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'])

for row, col in it.product(range(len(df)), range(len(df.columns))):
    print ("mygrid.SetCellValue({0}, {1}, {2})".format(row, col, df.iat[row, col])) # **

# Results : 
# mygrid.SetCellValue(0, 0, 1.1)
# mygrid.SetCellValue(0, 1, 2)
# ...
# mygrid.SetCellValue(2, 3, 15)
```

** For practical reasons I use print(...) in the code above

In real code instead of print(...) Use the following :

```py
mygrid.SetCellValue(row, col, str(df.iat[row, col]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an old minimal example from this page:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210108064222/http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/extendswxgridPyGridTableBase.htm

I updated it here as `PyGridTableBase` and `PySimpleApp()` are deprecated, and added a couple `self.` so it stops complaining.

```
import wx
import wx.grid


class GenericTable(wx.grid.GridTableBase):
    def __init__(self, data, rowLabels=None, colLabels=None):
        wx.grid.GridTableBase.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
        self.rowLabels = rowLabels
        self.colLabels = colLabels

    def GetNumberRows(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def GetNumberCols(self):
        return len(self.data[0])

    def GetColLabelValue(self, col):
        if self.colLabels:
            return self.colLabels[col]

    def GetRowLabelValue(self, row):
        if self.rowLabels:
            return self.rowLabels[row]

    def IsEmptyCell(self, row, col):
        return False

    def GetValue(self, row, col):
        return self.data[row][col]

    def SetValue(self, row, col, value):
        pass


data = (("A", "B"), ("C", "D"), ("E", "F"), ("G", "G"), ("F", "F"), ("Q", "Q"))

colLabels = ("Last", "First")
rowLabels = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")


class SimpleGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.tableBase = GenericTable(data, rowLabels, colLabels)
        self.SetTable(self.tableBase)


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "A Grid", size=(275, 275))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self)


app = wx.App()
frame = TestFrame(None)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Tested and running on:

```
Python 3.9.12
wx.version: 4.2.1a1
wxWidgets 3.2.1
```

[image: GridTableData]

Just a note to the WxPython team in charge of maintaining the demo.

Might be profitable to newcomers to have a `for dummies` 2nd simpler demo repository with all the current samples but as `minimal examples` such as the one above so we could quickly spot the minimal requirements for the examples/tweak them easily as a first approach (without having to first filter through all the bells and whistles of the advanced demo examples).

Then we could jump and see all that's possible if extended to it's limit with the full demo.